# How to find a modern tutorial for Ruby on Rails for Eclipse/Aptana?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I started studying Ruby on Rails. So far I installed  the Eclipse plugin Aptana Studio 3, then installed Ruby on Windows and ran simple Ruby programs.

However, I cannot find a modern tutorial for Ruby on Rails for Eclipse/Aptana